# "if" com um "matches()" ou várias comparações?

Tags: java, string, regex, if

Considerando que eu tenha uma variável do tipo `String tipoResidencia` que nunca será nula, e que preciso executar um teste, a solução padrão é essa:

```
if (tipoResidencia.equals("CASA") || tipoResidencia.equals("PREDIO") )
```

Mas se eu quiser utilizar `matches(regex)` para reduzir o código estaria fazendo errado? Exemplo:

```
 if (tipoResidencia.matches( "CASA|PREDIO") )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Algumas pessoas podem discordar, mas pra mim `RegEx` só em último caso. Neste caso específico acho que todos concordariam que a primeira forma é mais simples de executar.

Não acho que o fato da segunda forma ser mais curta justifique o seu uso. Ser mais curto não significa necessariamente ser melhor ou mais legível.

Enfim, quando os dois resultados são iguais, não tem efeitos colaterais, situações onde pode dar problema, não são prejudiciais de alguma forma, escolha qual lhe agrada mais. Eu [escolho a mais simples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), que neste caso é a mais básica, a que todo mundo reconhece.

Provavelmente dois valores é o limite do que compensa. Se tivesse vários valores para avaliar, eu provavelmente criaria um método para simplificar e evitar o `RegEx` (aí nem todos concordariam comigo). Aí internamente eu veria como resolver melhor a lista, se o parâmetro dele seria uma *string* ou um *array* (o mais provável). Seria mais performático que `RegEx`.

Comment: Gostei da referencia!

Comment: Outra coisa que eu posso sugerir é: mesmo que você saiba que a String que está usando não será nula, adote o padrao "CASA".equals(tipoResidencia) ... assim em outras situações você poderá evitar um NullPointerException

Comment: @PedroLaini concordo, com sua dica

tambe, podemo utilizar `if ( Boolean.false.equals(variavelBoolean) )` para variaves do tipo Boolean